# How does purchasing upgrades affect the cost of other upgrades?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I've been noticing that when I purchase upgrades in the Manor, sometimes the price of other upgrades will increase. Do all upgrades increase all prices, or are there certain ones which affect each other? If the latter, which ones are those?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Buying any upgrade in the Manor increases the price of all other Manor upgrades. Buying runes from the enchantress makes the other runes more expensive. The blacksmith's prices are tiered and fixed.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, feel free to improve the answer or explain your reasoning.